# Sorting the x axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Why does this code not plot the x-axis sorted by 'value'?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# creating dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['name'] = [1,2,3]
df['value'] = [4,3,5]

# sorting dataframe
df.sort_values('value', ascending = False, inplace= True)

# plot
plt.scatter(df['value'],df['name'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate, what you mean? You are creating a scatterplot, so the order of the values should not matter as long as corresponding numbers in `df[value]` and `df[name]` are in the respective same place. Can you maybe provide a plot and explain what in that plot is not the way you expected it to be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your choice of variable names, plus the seeming confusion surrounding the use of scatter plots, it seems like `name` may be a categorical variable that you'd like to plot on the x-axis, sorted by `value`.

If that's the case, I'd recommend initially plotting with `df.index` as the x-axis, and then changing the tick labels to `name` entries.  Use `reset_index()` after `sort_values` to get the correct index ordering.

Both Pandas and Pyplot should be able to do this without additional modules, but I had some trouble getting tick labels to line up. Instead, I found Seaborn's [`pointplot()`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html) handled this job without any trouble:

```
# sort, then reset index
df = df.sort_values('value', ascending = False).reset_index(drop=True)

import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.pointplot(x=df.index, y=df.value)
ax.set_xlabel("Name")
ax.set_ylabel("Value")

# Use name column to label x ticks
_ = ax.set_xticklabels(df.name.astype(str).values)
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PX]

Comment: How to sort data on the graph while the graph has not been plotted using pandas? I mean how to make the plot in order?